# Compare records with same field value from different Objects in apex?

Tags: apex, class, map, list

I have two lists with having the same field in a different object. How to compare the list of name is present in my list if yes then its should be update else it should only create a new record not adding the older record in my list.

```
 List<Project__c > ProjectList= [select id,Name,Opportunity__c from Project__c where Opportunity__c=:oppId];
 List<Role__c> RoleList= [select id,Name,Opportunity__c from Role__c where Opportunity__c=:oppId];
```

For Example

```
ProjectList =({Id=001, Name=Marry,Opportunity__c =aoQXX},{Id=002, Name=John,Opportunity__c =aoQXX},{Id=003, Name=Chris,Opportunity__c =aoQXX});

RoleList =(({Id=001, Name=Marry,Opportunity__c =aoQXX},{Id=002, Name=John,Opportunity__c =aoQXX})
```

Now My Question is I need to add only Chris in my RoleList instead of adding again Marry, john. how would I do that in apex?

```
for(integer i = 0; i < ProjectList.size(); i++) 
             {
                 for(Role__c Upd :RoleList )
                    {
                      
                        if(ProjectList [i].Name.contains(Upd.Name))
                        {
                            System.debug('Updated needs to done ');
                           
                            
                        }
                       else if(!ProjectList [i].Name.contains(Upd.Name))
                        {
                             System.debug('Insert only third not everything');  
                        }
                    }
             }
```

if I check my debug statement

```
Updated needs to done 
Updated needs to done 
Insert only third not everything
Insert only third not everything
Insert only third not everything
```

but expected should be

```
**Updated needs to done 
Updated needs to done 
Insert only third not everything**
```

Comment: Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The exact reason may differ but, in general, if you see yourself writing code like this

```
for(SObject1 obj1 :obj1List){
    for(SObject2 obj2 :obj2List){
        if(obj1.field__c == obj2.field__c){
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

that's a red flag.

Nested loops are unavoidable at times (and not inherently evil), but if you're doing a comparison like `if(obj1.field__c == obj2.field__c)` (which is nearly functionally identical to your `ProjectList [i].Name.contains(Upd.Name)`), that ends up being incredibly wasteful. There is a better way.

The general idea is that you have two separate loops, and use a Set or a Map.
The first loop gathers data, and the second loop compares against that data.

Applied to your situation, that'd look something like this

```java
Set<String> namesWithRoles = new Set<String>();

// gather data loop
for(Role__c role :roleList){
    namesWithRoles.add(role.Name);
}

// comparison loop
for(Project__c project :projectsList){
    if(namesWithRoles.contains(project.Name)){
        // already exists, just do an update
    // There's no need to make this an 'if-else'
    // The only way to get into this else block is if namesWithRoles does not contain
    //   the project's name
    }else{
        // doesn't exist as a role, add it for insert
    }
}
```

Note that Sets are case-sensitive. Your current code would allow role with name 'Jessica' to count as existing for a project with name 'Jess' (you're using the `contains()` method from the `String` class in your provided code), and using a Set, Map, or List would not display that same behavior.

If you need to do a check against multiple fields, then you'd want to start thinking about using a `Set<SObject>` instead of a `Set<String>`. Doing that, in effect, is comparing the hashcode of the objects against one another. It ends up being a shorter and faster way to do things compared to comparing multiple fields.